# Designing a classifier with minimal image data

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, data-science

I want to train a 3-class classifier with tissue images, but only have around 50 labelled images in total. I can't take patches from the images and train on them, so I am looking for another way to deal with this problem.

Can anyone suggest an approach to this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very broad but here are some recommendations:

- It could make sense to generate variations of your input images. Things like modifying contrast, brightness or color, rotating the image, adding noise. But which of these operations, if any, make sense really depends on the type of classification problem.
- Generally, the less data you have, the fewer parameters (weights etc.) your model should have. Otherwise it will result in overlearning, meaning that your classifier will classify the training data but nothing else.
- You should check for overlearning. A simple method would be to split your training data into a training set and a control set.  Once you have found that the classification is correct for the control set as well, you could do additional training including the control set.